# Orchard CMS as customer portal - adding custom authentication

Tags: authentication, orchardcms

I have an existing MVC project (purpose built customer portal) that I am integrating into Orchard CMS as a module.

The customer portal module has its own database containing user information, which I need to use for **customer** authentication.

However, I also want to retain Orchards user authentication for **admin** authentication to Orchard.

So essentially, I require two authentication schemes with two different login pages for this. One for customers and one for admins.

How could I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to cancel the idea of having 2 differnt login pages and moving your users to Orchards user table.

Then link these users to a specific role named like `My existing MVC users` and grant permissions to this role accordingly.

If you take this route some of the benefits would be

- bound to Orchards user database and therefore existing authentication handling
- existing permission stuff can be used / extended out of the box
- user management in one place
- extensible by using own parts (e.g. AddressPart, ContactPart, ...)

Another solution would be to replace the existing authentication by implementing `IAuthenticationService`. But this seems rather complex.